# Rails file upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, jruby

Enviroment: rails 3.1.1-3.1.3, jruby1.6.5,

View code:

```
    <%= form_for(@app_dr_dish,:multipart=>true) do |f| %>
          <%= file_field :commodity, :image %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit(t('app_dr.submit')) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Params:

```
Parameters: `{"utf8"=>"鉁?,
"authenticity_token"=>"ktJJQN6iVLH8MpFE1sp7EflhQg7E5JYVYpIzr3/SEMo=",
"commodity"=>{"title"=>"", "desc"=>"", "image"=>"2.jpg", 
"price"=>""}, "commit"=>"create"}`
```

Error Info:

```
    "image"=>"2.jpg",right info should be a object instead of a string:
    "image"=>#<ActionDispatch:
    :Http::UploadedFile:0x9b26b6 @original_filename="2.jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"windowslinux.jpg\"
    \r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/sjy/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart.3752.64590>, @content_type="image/jpeg">
```

If i add such a piece of code, it becomes normal. Is it a bug or what is happening ?

```
    <div class="field">/* view code*/
      <%= f.label :image %>
       <br/>
      <%= f.file_field  :image %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is exactly since you don't really specify but I think the code is functioning as expected...  Perhaps you need to try this:

```
f.file_field :image
```

The way your original example from part 2 of your question has the code, written, you would need to use `file_field_tag` instead of `file_field`.

[Read the docs for more info on how to use the file_field with a form like this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files).